# ArcGIS REST layer doesn't show up in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-rest-api

I try to show a WMS layer with OpenLayers 4.6.5 but the tiles don't show up.

I use the following code to load the [WMS layer as ArcGIS REST service](http://geoportal.amb.cat/arcgis/rest/services/Cartografia/MapaTopograficAMB1M_ETRS89/MapServer/):

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
    url: "https://geoportal.amb.cat/arcgis/rest/services/Cartografia/MapaTopograficAMB1M_ETRS89/MapServer",
    projection: 'EPSG:25831',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'Nivell 1k'}
  })
})
```

The browser network tab shows that tiles get loaded, but they are all [transparent](https://geoportal.amb.cat/arcgis/rest/services/Cartografia/MapaTopograficAMB1M_ETRS89/MapServer/export?F=image&FORMAT=PNG32&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Nivell%201k&SIZE=256,256&BBOX=218915.64900874346,5082756.632851081,220138.64146130628,5083979.625303644&BBOXSR=3857&IMAGESR=3857&DPI=90).

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/sf5u7rb9/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location may need adjusting by about 10km as tiles are not loading where you centered the view.  The main problem was that EPSG:25831 needed to be defined using proj4.  You will need to include the library `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>`

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:25831","+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");

var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
            url: "https://geoportal.amb.cat/arcgis/rest/services/Cartografia/MapaTopograficAMB1M_ETRS89/MapServer",
            projection: 'EPSG:25831',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'Nivell 1k'}
          })
        })
];
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [232350, 5070153],
    zoom: 15,
    minZoom: 12,
    maxZoom: 20
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right about the 2 problems: 1. Tiles are not offered for the centered area and 2. EPSG:25831 needs to be defined using proj4.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Tile Services are wierd and don't allways act the same way as other WMTS.
your code missed the `new projection = ol.proj.Projection` declaration and also misplaced.

Besides that you also had the map startiong location out of the layer bounds.
I set it to the service's minimal coordinates, you can modify it further from there.

A fixed code would look like this:

```
var layers = [
        /*new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),*/
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
            url: "https://geoportal.amb.cat/arcgis/rest/services/Cartografia/MapaTopograficAMB1M_ETRS89/MapServer"
          })
        })
];
var projection 
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [423690,4582541],
    zoom: 15,
    minZoom: 12,
    maxZoom: 20,
    projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
        code:  'EPSG:25831',
        units: 'm'
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with placement of projection (see https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.TileArcGISRest.html) and there is nothing wrong with format of the projection (see https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.html#.ProjectionLike). Can you also explain what your statement "ArcGIS Tile Services are wierd" means in context of this question.

Comment: It means they don't act like normal WMTS. Either way the oslution does work, it seems the main problem was the starting location of his map.

Comment: You have simply changed the view projection, which wasn't a requirement, and without the full definition of the projection needed to enable reprojection any other layers such as a background OSM wouldn't match the data overlay.